# Error connecting SQL magic to SQL Server in Jupyter Notebook (connection engine seems to works fine)

Tags: sql-server, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have a SQL Server database I want to connect to in Jupyter Notebook. My engine works fine but I can't get SQL magic to connect. I've read hundreds of posts and tried everything but still no luck. Here's where I am:

1. Created System DSN (with SQL Server driver) named jupyterCMS in OBDC Data Source 64 bit. Test connection runs successfully.
   [DSN connection test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32dAD.png)
2. Connection engine

```
from getpass import getpass
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

username = 'username'
quoted_password = quote_plus(getpass('Input Password: '))
server_name = 'servername'
database_name = 'dbname'

connection_string = f"mssql+pyodbc://{username}:{quoted_password}@jupyterCMS"
engine = create_engine(connection_string)
connection = engine.connect()
```

3. Verify connection engine works (output shows correct table names from the database)

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect

inspector = inspect(engine)
for table in inspector.get_table_names():
    print(table, end=', ')
```

4. Try to use iPython with SQL Magic: FAILURE

```
%load_ext sql
%sql mssql+pyodbc://[username]:[password]@jupyterCMS #here I actually put in the full username and password
```

I get this error

> MetaData.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind'
> Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
> postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
> or an existing connection: dict_keys([])

where I was expecting to see

> 'Connected: username@None'

I tried username and password with and without brackets but no difference. Also tried making System DSN with different drivers. Why would the engine work but not SQL magic? There are no special characters in my password

Comment: Is Jupyter running directly on the Windows host, or have you got it running in a Docker container? If it's running in a Docker container it will not be able to see or utilize any ODBC DSNs you create in Windows.

Comment: It's on Windows